# How to autoamtically transpile TypeScript to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am learing angularjs2 by reading a 2015 book `ng-book2` but the node package that it uses `tsc` to transpile typescript to javascript on the fly is discontinued is deprecated:

> npm WARN deprecated tsd@0.6.5: TSD is deprecated in favor of Typings
>   (https://github.com/typings/typings) - see
>   https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269 for more information

. I have other methods on different tutorials bu I'm wondering if there is any  consensus on how best to transpile at the development machine?

Here is the package.json that I use:

```
{
  "name": "ng-book2-reddit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -f ./*.js; rm -f ./*.js.map; rm -f ./intermediates/*.js; rm -f ./intermediates/*.js.map",
    "tsc": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "tsc:w": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc -w",
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/live-server --host=localhost --port=8080 .",
    "go": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run serve\" "
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "2.2.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.6",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "tslint": "3.7.0-dev.2",
    "typescript": "1.9.0-dev.20160409",
    "typings": "^0.8.1",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "1.0.0",
    "live-server": "0.9.0",
    "typescript": "1.7.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on your build tool. They each have a package to run `tsc` (either in-process or shelling out).

Comment: @ssube please refer to my `package.json` for the tools.

Comment: If you want to run `tsc` from the command line, I believe you need to install it globally. If you're using gulp or grunt, they have typescript modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case use

```
npm run tsc:w
```

In your `package.json`

> "tsc:w": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc -w",

Comment: As tsc is deprecated, isn't there an alternative easy method to do the same?

Comment: @Karlom tsc --watch

Comment: I mean, something that does not use tsc. I don't want to rely on a deprecated package. it will be futile in the long run.

Comment: tsd is deprecated, not tsc. See my answer.

Comment: I get this error: `> ng-book2-reddit@1.0.0 tsc:w /home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/first_app/angular2-reddit-base
> tsc -w

error TS6053: File '/home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/first_app/angular2-reddit-base/intermediates/app-02.ts' not found.
`. Any idea?

Comment: @Karlom Are you tried to execute tsc:w ? This error indicates only that app-02.ts file not found

Comment: Sorry I had messed the folder. Started from scrach and now its fine. I also did not realise that I need two separate terminals one running `npm run serve` and one `npm run tsc:w`

Comment: @Karlom With regard to different terminals, all right. You must use two different terminal for two different tasks

Comment: @Karlom If you are very uncomfortable with the terminal I recommend to take the next short course https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-the-command-line

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**
tsd is deprecated, not tsc.

`tsd` is used to install TypeScript type definitions and has been replaced by `typings`.

`tsc` is the TypeScript compiler.

Install `typings` command line utility globally with:

`npm install typings --global`

See here for more instructions on using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings).

An Example of installing Mocha TypeScript type definitions:

`typings install dt~mocha --global --save`

You can just have this in your packages.json under scripts:

```
    "tsc": "tsc",
```

You should create a `tsconfig.json`, [see here for an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Then run in your shell:

`npm run tsc`

You also have `typescript` packages in `dependencies` and `devDependencies`, you only need it in `devDependencies`.

Comment: Will you please elaborate how can I adjust my code to use typings instead?

Comment: You might find this online book is more up to date: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Following your instructions, I get this error: http://pastebin.com/FLx7nzfM